# Solving fifth order polynomial equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve this equation:

```
1/s^3 + 3s^2 + 4s + 1
```

But I am not able to solve it. A little help would be appreciated.

P.S: I am new to *Mathematica* and I am having difficulty with its syntax. If you correct the power then please comment that how to write it.

Comment: This actually is  fifth order equation, which typically do not have closed form solutions.  Use `Solve` or `NSolve`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: There is no equation. Back to elementary school!

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried searching the web about solving equations with Mathematica?

Comment: I have tried by making pairs, adding and subtracting and........ all the methods which can be done by hand. :)
@bbgodfrey Thanks for your reply. Next time you will see the change :)

Comment: Is your equation actually `s^(-3) + 3 s^2 + 4 s + 1 == 0` in _Mathematica_ syntax?

Comment: No, it is same as above. s^3+3s^2+4s+1

Comment: `s^3 + 3s^2 + 4s + 1` is not an equation. Do you mean `s^3 + 3s^2 + 4s + 1 == 0`, which is an equation in _Mathematica_.

Comment: Equations equate things and usually have the form left hand side == right hand side...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

```
eq1 = 1/s^3 + 3 s^2 + 4 s + 1 == 0;
eq2 = Simplify[s^3 # & /@ eq1]
```

> ```
> 1 + s^3 + 4 s^4 + 3 s^5 == 0
> ```

which demonstrates that the equation is indeed of the 5th order.

```
Solve[eq2, s] // N
```

> ```
> {{s -> -1.21261}, {s -> -0.506962 - 0.665378 I}, {s -> -0.506962 + 0.665378 I}, 
>  {s -> 0.446601 - 0.439765 I}, {s -> 0.446601 + 0.439765 I}}
> ```

## Edit

I note that, if one is using the Suggestion Bar, then evaluating

```
 1/s^3 + 3 s^2 + 4 s + 1 == 0
```

will return

[image: output]

Clicking on the 'solve for [s]' suggestion produces

[image: solution]

so this can be quite easy even for beginners.